# Box.Net users-on-behalf-of-enterprise-user working

Tags: box-api

In Box developer document they ask to contact them with the API key generated.

Reference:
http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-on-behalf-of-enterprise-user

Is there is any api(Java) to get the other users mail box with the admin credential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary purpose of "on-behalf-of" is to make calls on behalf of your company's users as an administrator.  A great use case is if you'd like to prepopulate your new hire's account with a set of folders before they start on day 1.

In order to get the listing of enterprise users in your account, you would use the following API call if you are an administrator: http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-all-the-users-in-an-enterprise.  This is currently not built into the Java SDK, but it is open source if you want to submit a pull request to it to add the functionality.